# MongoDB - Add array elements

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

When I am trying to run:

```
{$push:{"Training_to_Attend":["Python","DBMS"]}
```

My output is

> "Training to Attend" : [ [ "Python", "DBMS" ] ]

My expected output:

> "Training to Attend" : ["Python", "DBMS"]

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`$each`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) operator to add each element into the `Training_toAttend` array, instead of adding as an array.

```
db.collection.update(
{},  // Filter criteria
{
  $push: {
    "Training_to_Attend": {
      $each: [
        "Python",
        "DBMS"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T9bOCNc0Rvu)